# Unable to apply Clip Gain in LogicProX

Tags: logic-pro

I can't figure out how to get clip/region gain to work in LogicProX.

I'm applying gain to a clip as shown in the capture below, and I see the clip gain being applied to the selected clip. In cap I'm explicitly making it very large to be obvious and when played back that much gain should overload the audio, but the audio of the clip plays back at its original volume.

What am I missing here? Is there something else that needs to be enable for this to work? I've tried explicitly enabling region or track gain but that brings up a completely different UI for the entire track, which can't be the same as this clip gain setting in the tray?

From everything I've read, it seems that what I'm doing should just work, but I've never gotten this to work.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Clip gain not applied]

Comment: When I change gain in a region I can clearly see and hear the difference. Maybe check for updates and restart?

Comment: I can definitely **see** the change, but I don't hear it on playback. The clip above should be fully clipping and sound distorted - it doesn't. I'm on latest. This has been an ongoing thing for me for years - just finally had to ask because this makes no sense.

Comment: Looks like in the latest updates (10.7.5+, also with the new Clip Gain Tool) this now works as expected. Previously though it didn't work even over various new version updates, so I'm not sure what the problem was.

Comment: I’m glad they got it straightened out in the new versions.

Comment: So I had this working in one project, but now working in another project and again it is not working again. I can reduce gain until there's no signal left but the region continues to play back at original volume.

Comment: I suggest posting your problem in a Logic forum. Your chances of finding answers are much higher there than here where there are probably not many Logic users. Sorry for your trouble and good luck to you.